# Customizing source code of wso2 appm and wso2 emm

Tags: android, wso2

I want to customizing the source code of Wso2 appm/emm. Therefore I want to know what can we customize and upto what extent, where will I get the code to make changes(from github or with in the product). And also please tell what all I have to do to execute this changed code.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore I want to know what can we customise and upto what extent,

**App manager**

- The given link[1] provides some customisations that can be done.
- Additionally, you can customise the app subscription model to add a
  custom model such as paid subscriptions.
- There is no doc available on UI white labeling, but you should be
  able to customise the UI as well by editing the Jaggery apps of store
  and publisher.

  **EMM**

  - Lets say you need to plugin in a new device type that is not
    supported OOB, like blackberry. You can write a plugin your self and
    implement this functionality.[2]
  - You can customise the UI[3]
  - Customise the Email template[4]
  - White/Customise the Android agent[6]
  - White label iOS agent[7]
  - Event reporting[8]

  In both products you can customise the management console[5]

  > where will I get the code to make changes(from github or with in the
  >   product). And also please tell what all I have to do to execute this
  >   changed code.

  **EMM**
  Repos to build according to build order,

  - https://wso2.github.io/github-repositories.html

  **App manager**
  Repos to build according to build order,

  - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-appmgt
  - https://github.com/wso2/product-app-manager

  Prior to working on any code related changes, if you are planing on doing so, I highly recommend you to understand the architecture of the products[9][10]. More information about building WSO2 products is available here[11]

  [1].https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM110/Extending+App+Manager

  [2]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS100/Writing+Your+Own+Device+Connector

  [3]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Customizing+the+UI+and+Documentation

  [4]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Customizing+Email+Templates+for+Tenants

  [5]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Customizing+the+Management+Console

  [6]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Customizing+the+Android+APK+File

  [7]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/White+Labeling+WSO2+EMM+iOS+Agent

  [8]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Reporting+Critical+Events+via+Alerts

  [9]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Architecture

  [10]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM100/Architecture

  [11]. https://wso2.github.io/using-maven.html